# Unity container - register type based on resolved property of another registered type

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, unity-container

I am trying to register a type mapping from wrapping class's property to a type. Something like this - is it possible (all dependencies to **Inner** should be basically constructed using **Wrapper** and passing over a property)

```
public class Wrapper
{
    IDependencyForWrapper _dependency;
    Inner _inner;
    public Inner Inner{ get { return _inner; } }
    public Wrapper(IDependencyForWrapper dependency)
    {
      _dependency = dependency; //do other things here
      _inner = new Inner();
    }
}
```

....

```
container.RegisterType<Inner, Wrapper>(new InjectionConstructor(new ResolvedParameter<IDependencyForWrapper>()));
```

Comment: Can you make `Wrapper` generic, as in `Wrapper<Inner>`?

Comment: Yes, but i can't get my head around on how this would registration look like in that case..

Comment: Are you limited to Unity? You can do [Context based injection](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced.html#context-based-injection) with [simpleinjector](https://simpleinjector.org/)

Comment: Yes, we are limited to unity

Comment: @ArthurP I am unclear as to what it is you are trying to achieve.Unity will be unable to do the registration you are asking for as the two classes are unrelated. `Inner` appears to also be a tightly coupled dependency of `Wrapper`